# Почему не функционирует "Карусель" на Bootstrap 3?

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему не функционирует "Карусель" на **Bootstrap 3**.

Код:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="img/main-img1.png" />    
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/main-img2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/main-img3.png" />
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Стили bootstrap и js-файл подключаются локально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо! Решил проблему. js-файлы "почему-то" не подключались.

Comment: "удивительно" :D

Answer (score 0):

Откройте консоль и посмотрите. А так мы тут не экстрасенсы и по HTML коду вряд-ли кто-либо догадается до чего-либо.